# unordered_set pass by address

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-set

I have moved on to C++ from C and recently learning STL.

The last line gives pretty long error in STL style(Helpless) Or maybe I am new to templates thats why I find it helpless.

```
int insert(Forest *forest, int e1) {
    Forest::const_iterator te1;
    te1 = forest->begin();
    te1->insert(e1);
}
int main() {
    //some code here
    Forest forest = (5, myHash);
    insert(&forest, e1);
}
```

Forest is:

```
typedef unordered_set<unordered_set<int>, function<size_t(const unordered_set<int>)>> Forest;
```

EDIT:
After trying as one of answers suggested

```
Forest::iterator te1 = forest->begin();
te1->insert(e1);
```

It still gives same errors.

Comment: Show the error message, even if you think it's not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11, the items in a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` are all `const`. You can't insert into one of them, you have to remove it and re-add.

This is because you're determining the position in the parent set by its hash value, which might change if you add a new item to it. It's analogous to the keys in a `std::map` being `const`.

Comment: Sorry I don't get this, you meant C++11's `std::unordered_set` ?

Comment: I think, its not just C++11, you can't do it for `set<set<int> > Forest;` either, because it tries to modify an existing element, using iterator

Comment: IIRC, in C++03 it's not specified that the items in a `set` are const. In C++11 it was clarified that they always are, like the keys in a `map`, because if you change them you might change the position they should be in within the container.